# UIBarButtonItem looks bad in ios6

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uinavigationbar

I'm using NavigationBar for my application . in iOS7, my navigation leftButtonItem icon appears fine(http://prntscr.com/2vaha7). But on iOS6 , it looks like that : http://prntscr.com/2vafer.

My code :

```
_item2 = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

_item2.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderMenu.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(revealMenu:)];

[self.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:_item2 animated:NO];
```

How can i fix this visual issue instead of works also fine in iOS6 ?

Best Regards,

Onder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at : http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6

and : http://iosdevblog.com/2013/01/26/the-recommended-size-for-custom-uibarbuttonitem/

you will need to create a custom transparent back image for your button, and set it as the background image of bar button for ios 6 :

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:clearImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:clearImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

//edit : i firstly thought it was a back button, which you need to mak resizable like the following:

```
UIImage *buttonBack30 = [clearImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 6)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack30 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I created clearImage with the following code, but you can simply create a 34x60 image of any color :

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color andSize:(CGRect)rect {
// Create a 1 by 1 pixel context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
[color setFill];
UIRectFill(rect);   // Fill it with your color
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
```

}

```
UIImage *clearImage = [self imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] andSize:CGRectMake(0, 0, 34, 60)];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it's going to fix my problem, so i should apply whole ButtonItem in my app instead of works correct in ios6

Comment: you can apply that only for ios 6 with : 

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7)